# The "hamburger" button on my navbar is not working (bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a bit of a problem with the "hamburger" button on my navbar. When I click it,nothing happens. It worked before so I don't know what happened and can't seem to find where the error is.

If somebody can have a look I'd be very grateful.

CSS:(has nothing to do with the navbar, I've inserted it just in case)

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:100,200,300,400,500,600,700|Roboto+Condensed:100,200,300,400,500,600,700');
/*---------------------------------Navigation Bar*/ 



#navbar-nav {
  color: #ffffff ;
}
/*---------------------------------Footer*/
footer {
  background: #212529;
  color: white;
  margin-top:100px;
}

footer a {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
}

footer a:hover {
  color: #ced3d7;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.copy {
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-top: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
}

.footer-middle {
  padding-top: 2em;
  color: white;
}


/*---------------------------------Social Icons*/

/* footer social icons */

ul.social-network {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
  margin-left: 0 !important;
  padding: 0;
  float: right;
}

ul.social-network li {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0 5px;
}


.social-network a.icoFacebook:hover {
  background-color: #3B5998;
}

.social-network a.icoLinkedin:hover {
  background-color: #007bb7;
}

.social-network a.icoFacebook:hover i,
.social-network a.icoLinkedin:hover i {
  color: #fff;
}

.social-network a.socialIcon:hover,
.socialHoverClass {
  color: #44BCDD;
}

.social-circle li a {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.social-circle li i {
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.social-circle li a:hover i,
.triggeredHover {
  -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -ms--transform: rotate(360deg);
  transform: rotate(360deg);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

.social-circle i {
  color: #595959;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.8s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.8s;
  -o-transition: all 0.8s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.8s;
  transition: all 0.8s;
}

.social-network a {
  background-color: #F9F9F9;
}

HTML:
```

```html
<header>
<!-- Navigation Bar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
      <img src="assets/image/LOGO.png" class="img-fluid" alt="">
  </a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">News</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Music</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Video</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Shop</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
    
<!--Navigation Bar-->
    </header>
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Your HTML is incorrect. Look at the end of your code: the div, ul, and li are not well placed.

Here is a fiddle: https://www.bootply.com/jTv9CmmeO1

```
<header>
<!-- Navigation Bar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
      <img src="assets/image/LOGO.png" class="img-fluid" alt="">
  </a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">News</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Music</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Video</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Shop</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
        </div>
</nav>

<!--Navigation Bar-->
    </header>
```

Comment: I think you didn't have to be so rude about it, as I've just started coding a month ago, but thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @georgecx destress man, I didn't want to hurt you, you've all my heart you know, it's just a problem aof knowledge in english from my side, it's not my native language you know... Please apologize...